# Deleting a record in parent table and updating "DELETED" column in child table

Tags: plsql

I have a parent table(profiles) in which profile_id is the primary key and is a foreign key to 3 different child tables. (s_profile, p_profile, c_profile)

Now, i want to delete a record from the table profile and want to update a "DELETED" column in the child tables with sysdate.

However my script doesn't allow it saying "Foreign key violated- Child record found".

Is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of that foreign key constraint, if you want to allow deleting master while details exist?

Anyway, here's an example which shows what you might do; is it the right way, I can't tell (I suspect not - once again, it is cancels the purpose of the referential constraint).

Create two tables - master and its detail:

```
SQL> create table profiles
  2    (id_profile number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table s_profile
  2    (id         number primary key,
  3     id_profile number constraint fk_s_pro references profiles (id_profile),
  4     deleted    date);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Sample data and attempt to delete a master while detail exists:

```
SQL> insert into profiles values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into s_profile (id, id_profile) values (100, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> delete from profiles where id_profile = 1;
delete from profiles where id_profile = 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_S_PRO) violated - child record found


SQL>
```

Create a trigger on the master table which removes foreign key value and sets the date:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bd_prof
  2    before delete on profiles
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update s_profile s set
  6      s.id_profile = null,
  7      s.deleted = sysdate
  8      where s.id_profile = :old.id_profile;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's try to delete master again:

```
SQL> delete from profiles where id_profile = 1;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * From s_profile;

        ID ID_PROFILE DELETED
---------- ---------- ----------
       100            2018-10-03

SQL>
```

If you want to save foreign key value, you could alter detail table and add another column, say `deleted_id_profile` and populate it with the same trigger. Though, what would you do with it, if parent doesn't exist any more and you can't find any info about it?